# WSL (Kali-linux) dose not have internet accsse

Tags: linux, windows, wsl-2

I am using wsl on Windows 10 which does not have internet access,
My Internet works well in Windows
I used Wireshark to find the problem
,then executed ping command in wsl and this is the log in Wireshark on the vEthernet(wsl)
[image]

It seems that the IP settings are wrong and I don't know how to solve it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting help, I was able to solve the problem
i ran this command line as administrator

```
netsh winsock reset
```

then I reset my network
to do this type "network status" in the search bar and press enter
and at the end of the option click on Network reset
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem here using other distributions and resolved it using these steps:

First change wsl.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf
```

Add the folowing lines:

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

Now set the system dns server to desired address at /etc/resolv.conf:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

and add the folowing lines:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

reset the wsl using:

```
wsl --shutdown
```

PS: Use CTRL+X to Save and Exit Nano

Comment: It did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The "temporary failure in name resolution" issue typically indicates that your WSL instance is having trouble resolving domain names into IP addresses.

You can try the following steps to diagnose it!

1. Check Internet Access in WSL
2. Check DNS Configuration

   nameserver 8.8.8.8
3. Check Windows Firewall
4. Restart the WSL Service:

   wsl --shutdown

Comment: it dose not work and it does not connect to the DNS server  and 8.8.8.8

Comment: Have you tried to restart the Windows network stack: netsh winsock reset

Comment: thanks it worked aslo i used Network reset then restarted my computer